# Wait until function finish to run another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, jquery-deferred, deferred

I've encountered a problem that's driving me crazy for like 10 days now... Basically i have a function that fire (the `handleText`) and I want to wait the end of that function before running a second one (the `handleBackground`).

I've tried deferred and promises but I think I don't understand them well because I can't get it to work the way I want.

```
function handleText(){
    //BLAST INIT    
    var blastedwords = $('.baselineHeader').blast({
        delimiter: 'word',
    });

    //SHUFFLE ORDER IN ARRAY
    blastedwords = shuffleAds( blastedwords);
    function shuffleAds(arr){
        for(var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
        return arr;
    }

    //ADD CLASS TO SPAN CREATED WITH BLAST WITH A RANDOM DELAY
    blastedwords.each(function(index) {
        var min = 45, max = 100;
        var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        var that = $(this);
        var t = setTimeout(function() {
            $(that).addClass("test");
        }, delay * index);
    });
}

function handleBackground(){
    $('.baselineHeader').addClass('processed');
}

handleText();
handleBackground();
```

Right now, `handleText` start, and `handleBackground` (my second function that I want to run after the first one is finished)  fire at the same time and doesn't wait for `handleText` to finish.

I want `handleText` to run and wait for the each loop to give class to every span created with blast.js before running `handleBackground`.

Can someone help me with this ?
Have a great day folks :)

Comment: Call `handleBackground()` in the `setTimeout()` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend setting up a global variable **totalTime** which you can use to add up the inidivual delays. That way you can use another setTimeout to call the function handleBackground() after totalTime has passed.

```
var totalTime = 0;
blastedwords.each(function(index) {
  var min = 45,
    max = 100;
  var delay = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min) * index;
  totalTime += delay;
  var that = $(this);
  var t = setTimeout(function() {
    $(that).addClass("test");
  }, delay);
});
setTimeout(handleBackground, totalTime);
```

Comment: What a genius idea ! Why did i never thought about it... It worked like a charm, thank you :)

Comment: Hehe, thanks for the kind words kkqe - glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Define delay outside of your function and each iteration increase the delay so that the next one is a random amout of time after the last one.

```
var delay = 0;

blastedwords.each(function(index) {
    var min = 45, max = 100;
    delay += Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    var that = $(this);
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).addClass("test");
    }, delay * index);
});
```